# How to hard close/force close/kill the app from memory in Android using Appium in the same test

Tags: java, appium, appium-android

**This is my scenario**

1. Launch the  app and perform some steps
2. Hardclose/Forceclose/Kill the app from memory/Should not run in background
3. Launch the app again
4. Perform some steps
5. Assertion step

How to achieve this?

**I have tried the following methods**

1. `resetApp()` - it uninstall the app and install app again.
2. `closeApp()` - it just close the app but app is still running in the background.
3. `adb shell am force-stop <packagename>` - it just close the app but app is still running in the background.

But for my scenario it should delete from the background and app should not uninstall in **Android** in the same test (middle of the test).

Comment: resetApp() - it uninstall the app and install app again, wrong concept, it just clear app data and clear cache and open the app.

Comment: What you expected behavior? Launch the app again without clearing the app data and cache at the middle of test?

Comment: resetApp() uninstall and install the app for sure. I tried this method lot of times and confirmed. I want to clear the app from the background first then launch the app again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it, I think it will serve your purpose, use below line from where you want to launch the app  again

```
Activity activity = new Activity("appPackage", "appActivity");
driver.startActivity(activity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and add this to the capability :

```
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET,"false");
```

It should work as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

using **appium 2**:

```
driver.terminateApp("app package of the app");
```

to close the app, so you can open it again without closing it by hand, if you don't do this, it will open first time, second time will not, it is going to stay in the background, but it will be open after launching the test everytime, weither it is on back ground or not !